# AWS CLI s3 copy fails with 403 error, trying to administrate a user-uploaded object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Trying to copy a file from an S3 bucket to my local machine:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/audio-0b7ea3d0-13ab-4c7c-ac66-1bec2e572c14.wav ./

fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Things I have confirmed:

- I'm using version `aws-cli/1.11.13 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.4.0-75-generic botocore/1.4.70`
- The S3 Object key is correct. I have copied it directly from the S3 web interface.
- The AWS CLI is configured with valid credentials. I generated a new key/secret pair. I deleted the ~/.aws folder before re-configuring the aws cli. The IAM web interface online confirms that the user specific by arn is in fact making use of S3 via the CLI.
- The IAM user is granted the S3 full access managed policy, per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144757/aws-cli-s3-a-client-error-403-occurred-when-calling-the-headobject-operation). I removed all this users' policies, and then added only the AWS managed policy called AdministratorAccess, which includes "S3, Full access, All resources."  **Is there a different way to grant access via the CLI? I did not believe so.**

Bucket policy is intended to grant wide open access:

```
    {
        "Sid": "AdminAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        ]
    }
```

***How did I upload this object?***

I uploaded this object using AWS Signature v4 signed upload policy from a web app in the client browser directly to AWS.

Comment: Which region your buckets are in? How about adding region details in the ARN?

Comment: Can you post the debug output `aws --debug s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/audio-0b7ea3d0-13ab-4c7c-ac66-1bec2e572c14.wav ./`

Comment: @Ravi running with `--debug` flag did not yield anything beyond the original 403

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out, looking at the object properties, I can see the Owner of the OBJECT is "Anonymous," and also "Anonymous" user has full permission to this object.

I believe this is why I'm not able to access this object (I'm authenticated). Example: Since the "Anonymous" user has full permission, I am able to access via GET using a Web browser. This is functioning as designed. The S3 bucket is for uploading files which then become available for public consumption.

So when the file is POST'ed with the upload policy, the resulting owner is "Anonymous".

In this case, `acl=bucket-owner-full-control` should be used while uploading the object so the bucket owner can control the object.
Doing this, the owner will still be "Anonymous", however, it'll give the bucket owner (me) the full permission and I should be able to access the object after that, via AWS CLI.

Note that `acl=ec2-bundle-read` is a default that's actually hard-coded into the latest AWS SDK. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/7844c64cf248aed889811bf2e871ad6b276a89ca/aws-java-sdk-ec2/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/util/S3UploadPolicy.java#L77

It was necessary to copy **S3UploadPolicy.java** into my own codebase (it's an entirely portable little utility class, it turns out) and modify it in order to use `acl=bucket-owner-full-control`. And I have verified that this affords the administration of uploaded objects via AWS CLI.

Comment: Modifying upload policy java files is a complex way of solving this problem. I give 3 other ways to do it via command line my linked answer below...

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have 3 accounts (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`) with 3 canonical users (`canonical_user_account_A1`, `canonical_user_account_A2`, `canonical_user_account_A3`) and 1 IAM role (`R1`) that is in `A3`.

Files are in a bucket in `A2` and the files owner is `canonical_user_account_A1` (**this is on purpose**). When I tried to list the files I didn't got any error, **BUT** when I tried to download one of them I got

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

I have added `List` and `Get` permissions for a `R1` in the bucket policy and in the role permissions, in this case this is not enough, if the account were the bucket is not the owner it can't allow users from other account to `get` (download) files. So I needed to make sure that when I upload files I'm using:

```
    access_control_policy = {
    'Grants': [
        {
            'Grantee': {
                'ID': canonical_user_account_A2,
                'Type': 'CanonicalUser'
            },
            'Permission': 'READ'
        },
        {
            'Grantee': {
                'ID': canonical_user_account_A3,
                'Type': 'CanonicalUser'
            },
            'Permission': 'READ'
        },
    ],
    'Owner': {
        'ID': canonical_user_account_A1
    }
}

upload_extra_args = {'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'}

s3_client.upload_file(file_path, bucket_name, s3_file_path, ExtraArgs=upload_extra_args)

s3_client.put_object_acl(AccessControlPolicy=access_control_policy, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_path)
```

This allow both `canonical_user_account_A2` and `canonical_user_account_A3` to read and download the file.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar permissions issue when trying to download from s3 something I had uploaded previously. Turns out it has nothing to do with the **bucket** policy and everything to do with how your credentials are set when you upload and how you grant access privileges at time of upload. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45111153/695804) for more information on several ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case above error appeared when machine that was trying to contact S3 had **system time far from the current one**. Setting a correct time helped.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. THANK YOU! You just saved me tons of frustration down the road! (:

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 will return you Forbidden(403) even if file does not exist for security reasons.
Please ensure you have given proper s3 path while downloading.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1689)

Comment: I've confirmed the S3 object key. I suspect IAM policy complications, per [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144757/aws-cli-s3-a-client-error-403-occurred-when-calling-the-headobject-operation) however am baffled as to why the policy I have granted this user is not allowing access to the bucket via aws cli

Comment: can you delete this permission from your policy "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name", and retry

Comment: I made your suggested change, waited 1 minute, retried the operation. still same result. For now, I'm keeping both `"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"` and `"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"` as I have seen *that* be the magic bullet in other situations.

Comment: FYI if you use both IAM policies and S3 bucket policies simultaneously, the ultimate authorization is the least-privilege union of all the permissions.