# Download s3 bucket files on user's local using aws cli

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

How to download simple storage service(s3) bucket files directly on user's local machine?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution implemented in your own program code or an off the shelf application to do this? I assume the later because you have not tagged your question with a programming language tag.

Comment: I am going to use that command in bash script.
Which i will configured as cron job so it will automatically download logs on my machine

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that asking general questions like this is discouraged. You are expected to have full researched your issue and attempted to solve your issue yourself. If you still have specific issues, you can post a specific question including details of what you have tried so far. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 403 forbidden from s3 when attempting to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192084/getting-403-forbidden-from-s3-when-attempting-to-download-a-file)

Answer (score 90):

you can check the [aws s3 cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) so to copy a file from s3.

The  following  cp  command  copies a single object to a specified file locally:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/test.txt test2.txt
```

Make sure to use quotes `"` in case you have spaces in your key

```
aws s3 cp "s3://mybucket/test with space.txt" "./test with space.txt"
```

Comment: thanks Frédéric Henri but this will copy file on virtualmachine on aws,
I wants to download that file from s3 on my machine from where i am accesssing aws

Comment: The command will copy a file to an s3 bucket. The question asked is to do the reverse.

Comment: @GhostCode check on a bucket, this copies a S3 object to a file locally, you can even check doc I refer from the link and search for "Copying an S3 object to a local file"

Comment: Yes, I saw the command carefully now. I thought your answer was : 
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt
Sorry for being hasty

Comment: you can do the `cp` command as long as your user and bucket have `PutItem` permissions

Comment: I used this command for downloading a file from localstack and it worked fine.